# React-Redux export multiple connected components

Tags: reactjs, redux

what is the easiest code to export multiple connected components in one File at react-redux?

my parent component is this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Flashes/>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/client/customers" component={CustomersList}/>
                            <Route path="/client/customer/:id" component={CustomersForm}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
export default App
```

... and a child, which works:

```
import React from "react"
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createStructuredSelector} from "reselect";

class CustomersList extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
                const {foundCustomers, customers} = this.props;
                ...
             }
}

const structuredSelector = createStructuredSelector({
    customers: state => state.customers,
    foundCustomers: state => state.foundCustomers
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {getCustomers, dispatchCustomers, findInJson, findCustomers};

export default connect(structuredSelector, mapDispatchToProps)(CustomersList);
```

here i export with `export default`
and it works well.
but, in a other file i have multiple components in one file.
i didn't found any example to make a export like `export {..., ..., ...}` with connect.
thanks for help!

Chris

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449350/named-exports-with-redux/54449466#54449466

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks SakoBu, sounds good.
but, then, you end up with a not-connected class and a connected variable...?

Finally, i moved the part that need to be connected in a own file and component and exported that like above `export default ...`